# Cmake file for sycl CUDA backend

Tags: cmake, nvidia, sycl

I am having trouble writing a CMake file to offload SYCL code to the NVIDIA backend. My CMake file currently looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/icx)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/icpx)
project(HELLOESycl)

set(SYCL_FLAGS "-fsycl"
      "-fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda"
      "-fsycl-unnamed-lambda"
      "-Wno-linker-warnings")
FIND_PACKAGE(IntelSYCL REQUIRED)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} test1.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC sycl ${SYCL_FLAGS})
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SYCL_FLAGS})
ADD_SYCL_TO_TARGET(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} test1.cpp)
```

The error message is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sycl::_V1::runtime_error'
  what():  Native API failed. Native API returns: -42 (PI_ERROR_INVALID_BINARY) -42 (PI_ERROR_INVALID_BINARY)
Aborted
```

The code can be compiled and executed with the following command in the terminal, so the problem is not with the code

```
dpcpp -fsycl -fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda test1.cpp -o test
```

correct the cmakefile so it offload code to nvidia hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running afoul of CMake string concatenation rules. Your `${SYCL_FLAGS}` is actually:

`-fsycl-fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda-fsycl-unnamed-lambda-Wno-linker-warnings`

Try putting a space after each one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's a valid point, and after printing out the compilation flags, I found that it does indeed relate to the compilation flags. However, it's not related to how the flags are set. My current setting actually provides me with the following flags: -fsycl;-fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda;-fsycl-unnamed-lambda;-Wno-linker-warnings. The issue is that when you use FIND_PACKAGE(IntelSYCL REQUIRED), it sets sycl_flags to -fsycl. Therefore, we need to set sycl_flags after the find_package command to override this behavior.

Comment: Oh woops! I'd suggest accepting the other answer instead of mine, if you can!

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the SYCL compilation options (SYCL_FLAGS). When you use find_package(IntelSYCL), it can potentially overwrite the SYCL_FLAGS to use the -fsycl flag, which is specific to the Intel SYCL implementation. As a result, it may prevent SYCL from using the NVIDIA backend through the -fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda flag.